# How can I get current page URL in spring boot 2 webflux thymeleaf to set css active link

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Hi I have template which uses a default layout and fragemnt for the header and menu. What I am trying to do is detect the current page url so that I can add the required css to show active.

I have tried th:classappend="@{''} == 'find-all'? 'active': ''" however this always renders the current path as blank (ie current page). I have also tried ${#request.getCurrentPath} with an error saying cant find value or is null.

The URL is /find-all so it should detect this and apply the css but it doesn't seem to work.

The html fragment code is below:

```
<div class="header" th:fragment="header">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" th:href="@{/}">Time Keeping/Time Sheets</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item" th:classappend="@{''} == 'find-all'? 'active': ''">
                <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/find-all}">Find All</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/add-new-entry}">Add new Time Entry</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Maven dependencies snipet,

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As Requested below is just one of the controllers used.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

  private static final String currentMonthName = LocalDateTime.now().getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);
  private final TimeKeepingEntryService service;

  public HomeController(TimeKeepingEntryService service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  @GetMapping("/")
  public Mono<String> index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("metaTitle", "Time Keeping Application");
    model.addAttribute("month", currentMonthName);
    model.addAttribute("timeEntries",   service.findByMonth(currentMonthName));
    return Mono.just("index");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following code in Themeleaf to get the current page's URL.

```
th:value="${T(org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder).fromCurrentRequest()}"
```

**Update**

Since, getting the current URL using Thymeleaf doesn't seem to work, then we could do a workaround. We could fetch current our current URL in our `@Controller`, and send it through an attribute. This can be achieved using `HttpServletRequest`. The code would end up looking something like the one below.

```
@GetMapping("/")
  public Mono<String> index(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    model.addAttribute("metaTitle", "Time Keeping Application");
    model.addAttribute("month", currentMonthName);
    model.addAttribute("timeEntries", service.findByMonth(currentMonthName));
    model.addAttribute("currentUrl", request.getRequestURL().toString());
    return Mono.just("index");
  }
```

Now all you need to do is use this new attribute in your template.

```
<p th:text="${currentUrl}"></p>
```

**Update 2**

Since, any of the last options didn't work, you could ways try using `jQuery`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = $(location).attr('href');
    $("#id").text(url);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="id"></p>
```

Comment: Hi I get the following error org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1005E: Type cannot be found 'org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder'
 at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeLocator.findType(StandardTypeLocator.java:117) ~[spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.expression.spel.ExpressionState.findType(ExpressionState.java:155) ~[spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.TypeReference.getValueInternal(TypeReference.java:68)

Comment: Have you tried with `${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}`?

Comment: Yes, I get the following error. org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'requestURI' cannot be found on null

Comment: Do you mind adding your @Controller method that is fetching this page? The issue seems to be with your `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: I have added the controller for the index page, also this is constructed using Thymeleaf layouts.

Comment: Hi Alain, thanks for the update, I do not have a HttpServletRequest due to using netty as default with webflux. I have tried HttpServerRequest etc and get no defualt constructor found.

Comment: I added an option using `jQuery`, this one should work, since you don´t need anything out of Spring.

Comment: The jquery trick allowed me to get the page url and add the active class to the right menu item

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 0):

With Thymeleaf 3.0.x you can use:

```
 ${#ctx.getRequest().getPath()}
```

Unfortunately, so far I don't see any abstraction for both mvc and webflux.